# Object Number is not an instance of Date, Angular 2 form, typescript

Tags: forms, angular, date, typescript, datepicker

I'm working on an Angular 2 form. I'm getting problems working with a date variable.

For cross-browser compatibility on a calendar input, I'm using ng-pick-datetime (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime).

I get this error -> **ERROR TypeError: [object Number] is not an instance of Date**

The template code of the date input:

`<div class="input-control col-sm-6" >
     <label class="control-label" for="startDate">
       Starting date *
     </label>
     <owl-date-time
       [(ngModel)]="data.startDate"
       [dateFormat]="'DD-MM-YYYY'"
       [inputId]="'startDate'"
       [placeHolder]="'dd-mm-aaaa'"
       [type]="'calendar'"
       [dataType]="'date'"
       [autoClose]="'true'"
       id="startDate"
       name="startDate"
       #startDate="ngModel"
       [disabled]="!paramsService.isSolicitante()"
       [hideClearButton]="!paramsService.isSolicitante()"
       [max]="data.endDate"
       required>
     </owl-date-time >
 </div>`

The declaration of this startDate property in the typescript "Data" class:

```
startDate: Date = new Date();   
endDate: Date = null;
```

As you can see, the [dataType] property on the calendar picker is set to 'date', same type as the variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was an issue of assigning the data from one variable to another, with no use of new Date().